# Need help trying to launch HTML project

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code and want to run my local HTML and CSS project, but when I do I get this error message.
[localhost refused to connect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4vNz.png%27)

and my launch.json file looks like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Is your localhost running on port:8080 ?

Comment: If it's an HTML/CSS project, you don't need a server to see the page. Just open your File Explorer and double click on the HTML file to open it in a browser.

Comment: @Azu many requests will be blocked by CORS in that case.

Comment: @Azu, I was able to launch the files from my file explore. I would still like to try to launch from inside VScode. Do you think reinstalling VScode could fix it?

Comment: I've managed to make it work. You need to install this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer
Then hit (alt+L, alt+O) to Open the Server. You need to tell your Firewall to give it an access. The server runs at port 5500.

Comment: @Azu It works with Live Server! Thank you!